# In biological nitrogen fixation, the electrons required to reduce dinitrogen to ammonia are provided by which compound?

Tags: plant-physiology, nitrogen-cycle

The reaction is as follows:

N<sub>2</sub> + 16ATP + 8e<sup>-</sup> + 8H<sup>+</sup> → 2NH<sub>3</sub> + H<sub>2</sub> + 16ADP + 16P<sub>i</sub>

From where are the 8 electrons coming from?
We know that in photosynthesis, the electrons are supplied by the oxidation of water to evolve oxygen gas. What about here?

Comment: Welcome to SE BIology. Please take the Tour and read the Help on asking questions. You will find that you are expected to do some research yourself before posting. I would start with a source that explains the biochemistry of the process — [Berg et al online](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22522/) will give you the answer. Then, if there are still specific points you don't understand you should repost explaining precisely what these are. At present I am voting to close your question.